Electron webview does not handle css correctly
I have an external static web, which shows correctly in chrome as P1 below

When I use webview in electron with code
<webview src={url} style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} >
it shows a different view (the content within the red rectangle) as P2 below

It seems electron webview cannot handle some css properly which works fine in chrome.
Any suggestions?
